# Group By Linq Issue

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Items . The class looks like :

```
public class DeviceControllerDoorInfo
{

    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceControllerId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceControllerName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DoorId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DoorName { get; set; }

}
```

And the data looks like :

```
DoorId   DoorName  ControllerId ControllerName
------   --------  ------------ --------------

Door1    DoorOne   C1           C1
Door2    DoorTwo   C1           C1
Door3    DoorThree C2           C2
```

I want it to be converted , to look like it.

```
public class AccessGroupControllerDoorEntity
{
    public string ControllerId { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    public List<AccessGroupDoorEnity> Doors { get; set; }
}

public class AccessGroupDoorEnity
{
    public string DoorId { get; set; }
    public string DoorName { get; set; }
}
```

Group By the `ControllerId` and then list the door items.

How to do it ?

I tried :

```
            var controllersId = allDoors.GroupBy(e => e.DeviceControllerId).Select(x => x);
```

But does it make the Doors as List ?

I am not sure . Please help.

**UPDATE**

In my Data Service

```
    private AccessGroupEntity ConvertDoorsToEntity(DeviceControllerDoorInfo[] allDoors)
    {
        // return null if the object is invalid.
        if (allDoors != null)
        {
            AccessGroupEntity entity = new AccessGroupEntity();

            entity.ControllerDoorItems = new List<AccessGroupControllerDoorEntity>();

            //Convert to requested format instead of the below

            foreach (var door in allDoors)
            {
                entity.DoorItems.Add(new DoorInfoEntity
                {
                    DoorId = door.DoorId,
                    DoorName = door.DoorName,
                    ControllerId = door.DeviceControllerId,
                    ControllerName = door.DeviceControllerName
                });

            }

             return entity;
```

But instead I want `entity.ControllerDoorItems` to contain like the below grouped data :

```
  ControllerId -> C1
  ControllerName -> C1
  Doors ->          2 Objects
```

Comment: You will need to use GroupBy as you stated in the Title. Either show some effort your self or specify what exactly is your problem here?

Comment: What is the question here? Please clarify exactly what you're asking about. Are you asking how to get `controllersId` to be a list? Are you asking how to group your data? If so then please tell us what you want it to look like "to look like it" is not a good description since "it" is not specified. "How to do it?" is not a good problem description either. What is "it" here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please find the updated question.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder check my answer. Please

Answer (score 0):

```
DoorId   DoorName  ControllerId ControllerName
------   --------  ------------ --------------

Door1    DoorOne   C1           C1
Door2    DoorTwo   C1           C1
Door3    DoorThree C2           C2
```

When you use `GroupBy(e => e.ControllerId)` It will Return two lists (for the above example), which the first list has two Items Where `ControllerId` is **C1** and another list with one item that its ControllerId is **C2**.

So GroupBy returns Lists and not Items.

For your updated question:

```
List<AccessGroupControllerDoorEntity> grouped = allDoors.GroupBy(e => e.ControllerId)
        .Select(group => new AccessGroupControllerDoorEntity
                       {
                            DeviceControllerId = group.Key.Id,
                            DeviceControllerName = group.Key.Name,
                            Doors = group.ToList() 
                       });
```

Comment: @I have updated the question. Could you please find ?

Comment: But DeviceControllerDoorInfo does not contain ControllerId , It contains DeviceControllerId but then group.key.Id throws error . I guess as it returns two door objects , for that Key.Id or Key.Name do not make sense.  Could you please help.

Comment: Then you should use DeviceControllerId, this is the example that how can you use it. and please note that , `DeviceControllerId` of `AccessGroupControllerDoorEntity` can not be primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
         var list= allDoors.GroupBy(x=>new {x.ControllerId ,Name=ControllerName},
            (key, group) => new AccessGroupControllerDoorEntity
             { 
                ControllerId=Key.ControllerId ,
                ControllerName=Key.ControllerName,
                Doors = group.ToList()
             }))
            .ToList();
```